# Small Windows Form Chat application ideas?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, chat

I have a small application that I am building a Chat application into, so far I have the functionality to post messages!

I don't need a login as there will only be a small number of users and I will use their windows username for identification.

Has anyone done anything similiar? What else do I need to add? It doesn't need to be all singing and dancing as it is just for use within a small development team.

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple Thoughts:

1. System Tray Icon, easily hidden/restored, etc.
2. Since you have the Windows Accounts, send them an email (if you have exchange/ad email integration), if they're offline.
3. Auto-start on windows startup
4. Click-once / Auto Update
5. Web-based and/or Mobile-based versions.
6. Copy/Paste (with ability to paste images)
7. Not sure if it is useful, but it'd be cool: sending a message to a given "bot" ... fake username... such as a Distribution Group Name, sends an email to the Distribution Group and then emails sent to that distribution group get posted to that conversation
8. "Show other user my screen" -> mini screen-cap, etc.
9. Source-Control / Bug-Tracking Aware.

Just some random thoughts, let me know how it turns out.

Answer (score 3):

Chat Histoty ;)

SSL enabled communication

Requirement : It should not add unnecessary vulnerabilities to the system, Since it a related with Windows Authentication + There are open ports So there is a good chance of going something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

filesharing, webcam, auto away, timestamp!(this is where Live Messenger fails big time ;)

Answer (score 0):

- searchable chat history - searchable from the desktop search
- ability to chat to multiple people in the same conversation
- status notifications for /away or /busy

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to bring new messages to your users attention without stealing focus, perhaps implementing a hook into the [Snarl](http://www.fullphat.net/index.php) messaging program which is similar to Growl on Mac OS X?

This does mean that you would need to have the Snarl system installed on each of your workstations.